# Understanding Semidirect Products in Group-Theory through exercises.

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to prove (a) - (e) but am struggling with how to start.

$\bf{Question:}$ Let $H,K < G$ and consider the map $f: H \times K \rightarrow G$ given by $f(h,k) = hk$. The image of $f$ we will denote $HK$.

(a) Show that $f$ is injective iff $H \cap K = \{e\}$

(b) Suppose $H$ normalizes $K$. Show that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ and that $<H \cup K> = HK$. Further, show that $K \unlhd HK$.

(c) Let $HK$ be the semidirect product of $H,K$ and let $q: HK \rightarrow (HK)/K$ be the quotient map. Directly show that the restriction $q\restriction_H : H \rightarrow (HK)/K$ is an isomorphism.

(d) Show that $H,K$ commute: $hk = kh$ whenever $h \in H, k \in K$.

(e) Show that the map $f$ is an isomorphism onto its image (it's a bijection by part (a); you need to show it is a group homomorphism).

---

All I have so far for (a) is assuming $f$ is injective, then $f(h,k) = f(h',k') \implies hk = h'k'\implies h = h' \& \ k = k'$.

For (b), if $H$ normalizes $K$ then $\forall h \in H, \forall k \in K$ we have $k^{-1}hk = h$.

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: (d) is not necessarily true, so I don't know why you are trying to prove it. Also your remark at the end "For (b), if $H$ normalizes $K$..." is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a)

$\Rightarrow$: consider $h\in H\cap K$ and $k\in K$, then $hk=e(hk)$, that is $f(h,k)=f(e,hk)$. Using $f$ injective we conclude $h=e$

$\Leftarrow$: consider $h,h'\in H,$ $k,k' \in K$, such that $hk=h'k'$. From this we can show $hh'^{-1}=kk'^{-1}$. Since $hh'^{-1}\in H$ and $kk'^{-1}\in K$ we see $hh'^{-1}, kk'^{-1}\in H\cap K=\{e\}$. This implies $h=h', k=k'$

---

For b)

First, a small note. Your notion of normalizer is wrong. $H$ normalizes $K$ iif for all $h\in H$, $hK=Kh$.

To see $HK$ is subgroup of $G$, let $g_1=h_1k_1,g_2=h_2k_2\in HK$. Then
\begin{equation}
g_1g_2^{-1}=(h_1k_1)(k_2^{-1}h_2^{-1})=h_1(k_1k_2^{-1})h_2^{-1}
\end{equation}Since $H$ normalizes $K$, there is $k_3\in K$ s.t. $(k_1k_2^{-1})h_2^{-1}=h_2^{-1}k_3$. Then
\begin{equation}
g_1g_2^{-1}=h_1(k_1k_2^{-1})h_2^{-1}=(h_1h_2^{-1})k_3 \in HK
\end{equation}
Let's prove $<H\cup K>=HK$. It's easy to see $H\cup K\subseteq HK$ (just note $h=he$). Now, if $G'$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that contains $H\cup K$ then, for any $h\in H, k\in K$ we have $hk\in G'$, that is, $HK\subseteq G'$.

Let's prove $K$ is a normal subgroup of $HK$. Let $h'\in H,k,k'\in K$. Since $H$ normalizes $K$, there is $k''\in K$ s.t. $h'(k'kk'^{-1})=k''h'$, then 
\begin{equation}
(h'k')k(k'^{-1}h'^{-1})=(k'')h'h'^{-1}=k''\in K
\end{equation}

---

For c)

To see $q|_H$ is a group homomorphism, let $g\in h_1h_2K$, then there is some $k\in K$ such that $g=h_1h_2k=(h_1e)(h_2k)\in (h_1K)(h_2K)$. Conversely, $g\in (h_1K)(h_2K)$, then there are $k_1, k_2\in K$ such that $g=(h_1k_1)(h_2k_2)=h_1(k_1h_2)k_2$. Since $K$ is a normal subgroup of  $HK$, then $h_2 K=Kh_2$, which implies there is $k_3\in K$ such that $k_1h_2=h_2k_3$, so we conclude
\begin{equation}
g=h_1(h_2k_3)k_2 \in h_1h_2K
\end{equation}To see $q|_H$ injective, let $h_1,h_2\in H$ such that $h_1K=h_2K$. There is some $k\in K$ for which 
\begin{equation}
h_1e=h_2k \Rightarrow h_1h_2^{-1}=k\in H\cap K=\{e\} \Rightarrow h_1=h_2
\end{equation}To see $q|_H$ surjective, let $aK$ in $HK/K$ with $a=hk\in HK$. We see $aK=hK$. Indeed, $z\in aK$, then $z=h(kk')$ for $k'\in K$, that is, $z\in hK$. Conversely, $z\in hK$, then there is $k''\in K$ such that $z=hk''=hkk^{-1}k''=ak^{-1}k''\in aK$

---

Since (d) is not necessarily true, as pointed out in the comments, (e) is not necessarily true either.

Comment: For Question (a), in the $\Leftarrow$ direction, you claimed that $h,h' \in H$, $k, k' \in K$ are such that $hk=h'k'$ and that from this we can show $hh'^{-1} = kk'^{-1}$. How did you show this as I'm having troubles see how you showed this.

Comment: Yes, now that you mention it, what I wrote is not entirely correct. What is correct is, $hk=h'k'\Rightarrow h'^{-1}h=k'k^{-1}$. The proof is this: if $hk=h'k'$ then, by multiplying both values on the right by $k^{-1}$ we obtain $h=h'k'k^{-1}$. Again, multiplying both values on the left by $h'^{-1}$ we obtain $h'^{-1}h=k'k^{-1}$

Comment: I see, incidentally that is what I had in mind as a correction. Hmm, I too am puzzled that if (d) is not true, then why would my professor offer it as a practice problem. Perhaps he is trying to get the students to think more critically about whether what he gives us is true or not.

Comment: For the end of question (a), when you showed that $(h'k')k(k'^{-1}h'^{-1}) = k'' \in K$, doesn't $k''$ have to equal $k$ for the proof to hold or do I misunderstand what it means to show that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $HK$?

Comment: It is a misunderstanding. A subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is a normal subgroup iif, for any $g\in G$, $gNg^{-1}=G'$. This is equivalent to saying that, for all $n\in N, g\in G$, there is $n'\in N'$ s.t. $gng^{-1}=n'$. But this does not necessarily imply $n'=n$